# React Error – Each child in a list should have a unique “key” prop only on the first component rendered

Tags: reactjs

So I am trying to clean up some errors on my project and this one seems to want to stick around.

`Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

However, I only get this error on the first component that is rendered, and I am already supplying it a key. Here is the section of code in question.

```
bookings.list.map((request) => (
              <RequestListItem request={request} key={request.id}/>
            ))
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I have already tried adding a timeout, but the extra time didn't change anything.

Comment: Maybe one or more requests doesn't have an id? Or multiple requests have the same id?

Comment: its just seed data that I made, and they all have id's. I find it weird that only the first component throws the error and the subsequent ones don't, especially because they are all written the same

Answer (score 1):

When you're looping over react components and generating a list they each need a unique key.

```
bookings.list.map((request, index) => (
  <RequestListItem key={index} request={request}/>
))
```

What you're doing seems fine but no need to use a custom name or id, just receive the second index arg and use it.  (However your code should probably work if that `id` actually exists and is unique.